# Check if array is ascending

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a Java array `int[] field = new int[9]` that looks like this: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}

In a method  `public static boolean isSorted(int[] field, boolean isAscending)` I want to check if the array is ascending or descending. I tried this:

```
boolean fetch = false;
            if(field == null){
                fetch = false;
            }
            else if(isAscending){
                for(int i = 0; i < (field.length-1); i++){
                    if(field[i] > field[i+1])
                        fetch = false;
                    else
                        fetch = true;
                }
            }
            else if(!isAscending){
                for(int i = 0; i <= (field.length); i++){
                    if(field[i] < field[i+1])
                        fetch = false;
                    else
                        fetch = true;
                }
            }
            return fetch;
    }
```

However, when applying the method to the array mentioned above, I get two different results when the parameter is `isAscending` is passed once true and once false into the method. The result should be false for both cases because there are ascending AND descending numbers in the array at the same time. I know that the issue lies within the structuring of the code.

How can I imporve this and get to the desired result?

Comment: After the first `false` break out of the loop.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it. Thank you verry much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your code. First of all, when `isAscending` is `false` you are trying to access indices outside the bounds of the array. The loop should stop at the second last index just like in the first loop. Secondly, the only values that affect your return value is the last two values in the array. since every iteration you are setting a new value of `fetch`, overwriting all previous values. Instead of this you can assume the array is sorted, then once you find the first pair of unsorted values set `fetch` to `false`.

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] field, boolean isAscending) {
    boolean fetch = true;
    if (field == null) {
        fetch = false;
    } else if (isAscending) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (field.length-1); i++) {
            if (field[i] > field[i+1]) fetch = false;
        }
    } else if (!isAscending) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (field.length-1); i++) {
            if (field[i] < field[i+1]) fetch = false;
        }
    }
    return fetch;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the loop second to comply with the bounds of the array. Breaking the loops when false is returned fixed the overwriting of the fetch variable. Thank you!